# Python - Assigning values to multidimensional list

Tags: python, nested-lists

I want to assign word, translation, and notes to one index in the list, but I keep getting errors. I want to go increment the index each time it goes through the loop, assigning the variables to the same index. I'm new to Python so any help is appreciated. I want to be able to search for the words later so if there is a better way to do so please explain it.

```
num = 0
listOfWords = [[] for i in range(3)]

def WriteToFile():
    word = ""
    while word != "quit":
        word = input(str("Enter the word: "))
        if word != "quit":
            listOfWords[num][num][num].append(word,translation,notes)
            num += 1
        else:
            break
```

Comment: Also, if my explanation is not clear, just let me know.

Comment: How many dimensions does your list have?

Comment: Supposed to have three. @ForceBru

Comment: Yet it has two, because `[[] for _ in range(3)]` is a list that holds three lists.

Comment: I guess that's true.That's what I expected it to do. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're complicating yourself a bit much. You can append any number of lists to a `listOfWords`, and thus get the data structure you need.

Here's what I would, though I assume you define `translation` and `notes` elsewhere, I also input them:

```
listOfWords = []

word = ""
while word != "quit":
    word = input(str("Enter the word: "))
    if word != "quit":
        translation = input(str("Enter the translation: "))
        notes = input(str("Enter the notes: "))
        listOfWords.append([word, translation, notes])

print(listOfWords)
```

Output:

```
Enter the word: Hola
Enter the translation: Hello
Enter the notes: greeting
Enter the word: Perro
Enter the translation: Dog
Enter the notes: animal
Enter the word: quit
[['Hola', 'Hello', 'greeting'], ['Perro', 'Dog', 'animal']]
```

Comment: Ah that seems to be what I need. With that, would I be able to search through listOfWords? If I entered either the translation or the word, would I be able to print the corresponding information?